# C# XML serialization query attribute without name

Tags: c#

I need to create XML like below after using XMLSerializer. I created class as shown below.

Required Output:

```
<Item Price="000000002659"UnitOfMeasure="GALLONS">
    <TaxAmount Included="TRUE" Amount="000000000174"/>
```

Class definition :

```
public class Item
{           
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Price;
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string UnitOfMeasure;      
    [XmlElement("")]
    public TaxDetails taxdetails;
}

public class TaxDetails
{
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string TaxAmountIncluded;
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Amount;
}
```

After i create Item object with values, i would use 
  `ObjectToXMLString()` to create XML.
however this class definition creates the output like

```
<Item Price="000000002219" UnitOfMeasure="GALLONS">
    <taxdetails TaxAmountIncluded="Y" Amount="000000000000" />
```

I need to get rid of tag name taxdetails, but not sure how to define the TaxDetails class that would do that. Can anyone help me with definitions.

Comment: "i would use ObjectToXMLString() to create XML" Can you show what you mean by this? Usually when using `XmlSerializer` all you do is to call `serializer.Serialize(myObject)`. Apart from this in order to ignore a member from being serialized you should mark it with `XmlIgnore`.

Comment: Rename `TaxAmountIncluded` to `Included`, then rename `taxdetails` to `TaxAmount`

Answer (score 0):

The field in the `Item` class is named`taxdetails`, which is why that's the default element name as well.

You can override the element name and attribute name by specifying the name you want in the attributes from `System.Xml.Serialization`, or you can rename your class members.

I've done one of each in this example - renamed the member of `Item`, and specified the name of the attribute under `TaxDetails`.

```
public class Item
{
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Price;
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string UnitOfMeasure;
    [XmlElement()]
    public TaxDetails TaxAmount;
}

public class TaxDetails
{   
    [XmlAttribute("Included")]
    public string TaxAmountIncluded;
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Amount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the XML look like this:

```
<Item Price="000000002659"UnitOfMeasure="GALLONS">
    <TaxAmount Included="TRUE" Amount="000000000174"/>
```

And your current attempt looks like this:

```
<Item Price="000000002219" UnitOfMeasure="GALLONS">
    <taxdetails TaxAmountIncluded="Y" Amount="000000000000" />
```

You can see the two differences.  "TaxAmount" is called "taxdetails", and "Amount" is called "TaxAmountIncluded".  What you need to do is change the name of your properties so that they match:

```
public class Item
{           
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Price;
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string UnitOfMeasure;      
    [XmlElement("")]
    public TaxDetails TaxAmount;
}

public class TaxDetails
{
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Included;
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Amount;
}
```

Basically rename `TaxAmountIncluded` to `Included`, then rename `taxdetails` to `TaxAmount`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
public class Item
{           
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Price;
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string UnitOfMeasure;      
    [XmlElement("")]
    public TaxDetails TaxAmount;
}

public class TaxDetails
{
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Included;
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Amount;
}
```

or

```
public class Item
    {           
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string Price;
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string UnitOfMeasure;      
        [XmlElement("TaxAmount")]
        public TaxDetails taxdetails;
    }

    public class TaxDetails
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string Included;
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string Amount;
    }
```